# How to create an input loop?

Tags: c, loops, input

I'm looking for a way to write an input loop that continues to print prompts until the user enters a blank line.

This is what I want to do:

Loop starts, prints prompt `>` to the command line. User enters a line that ends with '\n', my program does whatever with that line, and then prints `>` again. This continues until the user enters a blank line (`\n`), at this point the loop terminates.

Comment: Using recursion is better because it makes the code simpler. However, it also makes the code more unreadable.

Comment: @QuipYowert No it isn't. What if the user enters 100,000 lines? A simple `while` loop would handle this case easily, while a recursive program could crash because the recursion would be too deep (leading to a stack overflow and a segmentation fault).

Comment: @QuipYowert: why recursion when a simple loop would do just fine?

Comment: In that case, I might as well write a Bayesian static analysis program to catch segfaults. (in Haskell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple `scanf` version can also be used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXL 64

int main (void) {

    char str[MAXL] = {0};

    printf ("\n Enter a string ([enter] alone to quit)\n");

    while (printf (" > ") && scanf ("%63[^\n]%*c", str) == 1)
    {
        /* do whatever in your code */
        printf ("   result: %s\n", str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_enter_quits

 Enter a string ([enter] alone to quit)
 > string
   result: string
 > another
   result: another
 >
```

**Note:** `MAXL-1` added as maximum width specifier for `scanf` to prevent write beyond end of array.

---

### `getline` Example

`getline` by dynamically allocating the line buffer allows you to accept a line as long as you want to give it. It can be billions of characters (up to the extent of your memory). This is a strength and a weakness. If you need to limit the amount of data you accept, it is up to you to check/validate/etc....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

    char *str = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    ssize_t nchr = 0;

    printf ("\n Enter a string ([enter] alone to quit)\n");

    while (printf (" > ") && (nchr = getline (&str, &n, stdin)) > 1)
    {
        str[--nchr] = 0;                /* strip newline from input */
        printf ("   (str: %s)\n", str); /* do whatever in your code */
    }

    if (str) free (str);

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getline_enter_quits

 Enter a string ([enter] alone to quit)
 > string one as long as you want
   (str: string one as long as you want)
 > string 2 make it 1000 chars.........................................
   (str: string 2 make it 1000 chars.........................................)
 >
```

---

### `scanf` Dynamic Allocation

You can also have `scanf` dynamically allocate the space for you by using the `m` conversion specifier (older versions of `scanf` use the `a` conversion specifier for this purpose). You must also provide a `pointer-to-pointer` to accept the address in this case. (e.g. `scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &str)` ).

#include 
    #include

```
int main (void) {

    char *str = NULL;

    printf ("\n Enter a string ([enter] alone to quit)\n");

    while (printf (" > ") && scanf ("%m[^\n]%*c", &str) == 1)
    {
        printf ("   (str: %s)\n", str); /* do whatever in your code */
        if (str) free (str);            /* you must free each loop  */
        str = NULL;
    }

    if (str) free (str);

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_dyn_enter_quits

 Enter a string ([enter] alone to quit)
 > some string as long as you want
   (str: some string as long as you want)
 > another string any length .......... ............. .............
   (str: another string any length .......... ............. .............)
 >
```

Comment: Maybe use [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) instead of `scanf`? Then you wouldn't have to worry about buffer overflows, and you wouldn't have to hardcode the length into the format string.

Comment: True, but then I would need to include code to strip the newline from the line buffer. It's a trade-off. I do it with `scanf`, `fgets`, and `getline`. All have there pluses and minuses... `scanf` is by far the simplest for a one-off prompt situation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If I didn't know how long the user-entered string will be, how could I alter your code to account for this?  Would I simply `malloc` `str` after the user enters their input?

Comment: Easy, use `getline`. You could give it billions of chars (until you run out of memory). I'll add an example.

Comment: @PythonNewb I added **both** a `getline` example and an example showing dynamic allocation with `scanf`.  You will find competing view as to which one is better.  `scanf` implementations can vary, but within the reasonable past, either should work for you.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that's awesome! Thanks for going through all the effort to show me the different implementations. I'll have no problem at all implementing this into my code.

Comment: Sure! They are all just tools you need to add to your C toolbox. (and it is a really big toolbox). You can do the same thing with `fgets` as well. All slightly different from the next, but all capable of doing the job. Once you have them all in your toolbox, you can decide which one to use based on the task at hand. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Would something along these lines answer your needs?

```
int ret;
// Basically, in order, 1 to indicate the file descriptor of the standard output
// ">" as the string you want to print
// 1 as the number of characters you want printed.
write(1, ">", 1);
while ((ret = read(0, buff, SizeBuff)) > 0) {
    buff[ret] = 0;
    if (buff[0] == '\n' && strlen(buff) == 1)
        return (0);
    /*Do your stuff*/
    write(1, ">", 1);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works? I thought write() was for files, rather than command line printing.

Comment: @PythonNewb Comments are in the code, explains simply the write parameters. If any other questions, just ask.

Comment: Why `write` when there is `printf`? (In this case, followed by `fflush` to ensure the prompt appears. Or doesn't `write` need flushing?)

Comment: @Jongware Why write? Because we want one character. Screw it. Why call printf and THEN call flush for *one* character? Write will write whatever happens. I generally find it more reliable than printf. Except when you are formatting. :-) Oh and also i much prefer using basic calls when possible. Printf inits va-args before even starting to think about what it has to print.

Comment: @Jongware Actually... Now that i just wrote that, why in the world would you use printf? O_o